# Best way to backup Gentoo install from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, backup, gentoo

I am messing around with Gentoo and I have never done so before but installing takes forever. So when I get a stable base establish I want to back up my Gentoo install to Ubuntu so if I mess it up I can just restore. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick answer will be to just use `dd` to make an image of the binary install. This an accurate restoration of the specific installation. See [Learn the DD command](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/learn-the-dd-command-362506/) on linuxqueations.

But, reading again, it seems that you want something like preparing your own distribution. For this you can look at [Gentoo's Catalyst](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/releng/catalyst/):

> "The goal of the catalyst project is to provide a single multi-faceted tool that can reliably build all aspects of a Gentoo Linux release: stage tarballs, GRP package sets, and install CDs."

Or, better for your type of dynamic needs from the installation, there is this article:
[Build Your Own Live-CD or Live-DVD](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Build_Your_Own_LiveCD_or_LiveDVD).

> "This article will show you how to create your own LiveCD. This method
>   has the following advantages over Gentoo's own Catalyst tool:
>
> - The build source will not be deleted between iterations of LiveCD creation. This will allow you to periodically sync, update, merge and
>     customize your environment the same way you do it with a real system.
> - ...
>
> "

Comment: I was also thinking the DD tool, though I have Gentoo on a 60GB partition and I will only have it about 6GB full, will DD create an image that is bigger than 6GB?

Comment: If I compressed all the files when mounting it from Ubuntu can I just restore them to the same partition if I want to restart?

Comment: It is not so easy to image only part of the drive, because if your drive is even a little fragmented you would not know what parts you need to take... But see the link I added for `dd`, search for the section about imaging a partition from another machine with `netcat`. This section also deals with piping through a packer.